# Bootstrap lag in Chrome on Mac

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've written a basic HTML and CSS file using Bootstrap and it works fine on my work computer with Chrome version 27.0.1453.110, but when I try to open the file in Chrome on my personal Mac(don't know the Chrome version) it opens VERY slowly, and lags when scrolling(like almost doesn't scroll at all!).  What could I have done wrong, or excluded from the coding? It's a simple test page, with a background image, nav bar, footer and some text.

```css
/*
 * Globals
 */

/* Links */
a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

/* Custom default button */
.btn-default,
.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-shadow: none; /* Prevent inheritence from `body` */
  background-color: rgba(96,96,96.75);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}


/*
 * Base structure
 */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(back1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
}
body {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

/* Extra markup and styles for table-esque vertical and horizontal centering */
.site-wrapper {
  display: table;
  margin-top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120%; /* For at least Firefox */
  min-height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 400px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
          box-shadow: inset 0 0 400px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}
.site-wrapper-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.cover-container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

/* Padding for spacing */
.inner {
  padding: 30px;
}


/*
 * Header
 */
.masthead-brand {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.masthead-nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.masthead-nav > li + li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.masthead-nav > li > a {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #B8B8B8; /* IE8 proofing */
  color: rgba(184,184,184.4);
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
.masthead-nav > li > a:hover,
.masthead-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: white;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
.masthead-nav > .active > a,
.masthead-nav > .active > a:hover,
.masthead-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: white;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .masthead-brand {
    float: left;
  }
  .masthead-nav {
    margin-top: -20px;
    float: right;
  }
}


/*
 * Cover
 */

.cover {
  color: black;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.cover .btn-lg {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.blockquote-reverse {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
}
.lead {
  text-align: center;
}
/*
 * Footer
 */

.mastfoot {
  color: #999; /* IE8 proofing */
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
.mastfoot a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*
 * Affix and center
 */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Pull out the header and footer */
  .masthead {
    position: fixed;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.9),rgba(0,0,0,.8),rgba(0,0,0,.8),rgba(54,54,54,.75), rgba(54,54,54,0)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background:      -o-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.9),rgba(0,0,0,.8),rgba(0,0,0,.8),rgba(54,54,54,.75), rgba(54,54,54,0)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background:    -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.9),rgba(0,0,0,.8),rgba(0,0,0,.8),rgba(54,54,54,.75), rgba(54,54,54,0)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background:         linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.9),rgba(0,0,0,.8),rgba(0,0,0,.8),rgba(54,54,54,.75), rgba(54,54,54,0)); /* Standard syntax */
    top: 0;
 left: 0;
  }
  .mastfoot {
    bottom: 0;
  }
  /* Start the vertical centering */
  .site-wrapper-inner {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  /* Handle the widths */
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 100%; /* Must be percentage or pixels for horizontal alignment */
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Cover Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="cover.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="site-wrapper">

      <div class="site-wrapper-inner">

        <div class="cover-container">

          <div class="masthead clearfix">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3 class="masthead-brand">Pith and Prose</h3>
              <nav>
                <ul class="nav masthead-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                  <li style="margin-right: 13px"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="inner cover">
      <div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12" style="display: table; padding-top: 200px; width: 104%; height: 750px; margin-left: -20px">
    
              <h1 class="cover-heading">Landing page.</h1>
              <p class="lead">This is where everyone will "land" when they come to your page.  We can put a little introduction to the whole blog and everything.</p>
       <br/><br/><br/><blockquote class="blockquote-reverse"><p>"The business of life is the aquisition of memories...in the end, that is all there is."</p><footer><cite>Unknown</cite></footer><br/><br/>
              <p class="lead">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Learn more</a>
              </p>
     
   </div></div></div>
            <div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12" style="display: table; padding: 30px 30px 100px; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8); width: 98%; height: 500px; margin-left: -20px">
        <h1 class="cover-heading" style="color: white; font-weight: bold;">Latest Post</h1>
     <p class="lead" style="color: white; font-weight: bold;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vestibulum orci nec risus pulvinar, nec mattis ipsum accumsan. 
             Nam faucibus, velit sed laoreet aliquam, mi dolor vestibulum orci, rutrum volutpat libero libero in justo. Praesent tincidunt, 
             lorem pretium pharetra congue, dolor arcu fermentum nibh, non finibus nisi metus auctor nisi. Nulla bibendum urna a lacus auctor, sit amet 
             vulputate lacus finibus. Morbi vel felis sit amet odio condimentum ullamcorper ac in mauris. Proin vitae vestibulum felis, ac ornare sapien. 
             Praesent sit amet mi elementum, porta turpis quis, varius nisl. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse 
             commodo sed lectus id tempor. Vivamus ultrices ullamcorper augue vitae condimentum. Nulla gravida imperdiet molestie. Donec sed imperdiet 
             tellus. Nulla fringilla nunc vel ex fringilla semper.<br/><br/>Donec sit amet tincidunt dui. Suspendisse ex ex, luctus non imperdiet a, ornare 
             sed massa. Proin eget ultricies tellus. Quisque nec orci vel augue tristique tincidunt vel id ligula. Duis tincidunt placerat rhoncus. Aenean
             eget ligula vel ligula hendrerit consequat. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean massa magna, volutpat sit amet ligula id, convallis fringilla ante. 
             Sed semper porttitor nisi, sit amet dignissim nulla lobortis a. Suspendisse hendrerit cursus sapien eu dignissim. Quisque pretium, nulla 
             ut malesuada luctus, enim sapien vulputate diam, efficitur maximus elit metus at lacus. Curabitur iaculis lobortis odio et porttitor. Sed 
             et congue ipsum.<br/><br/>Nulla ut dictum neque. Etiam placerat eros et mattis facilisis. Curabitur rutrum interdum est ornare suscipit. Nullam 
             mauris tortor, porta at cursus quis, finibus vel tortor. Nullam aliquam hendrerit nunc in tristique. Proin a leo risus. Maecenas interdum 
             pellentesque dui, rhoncus hendrerit massa scelerisque ut.<br/><br/>Nulla tempor congue tellus ac imperdiet. Ut facilisis erat eget porta bibendum. 
             Vivamus vitae nulla nec dolor laoreet finibus. Sed diam nibh, ornare nec maximus a, accumsan vitae diam. In convallis lobortis dolor a varius. 
             Sed a nisl in diam dapibus maximus ut sit amet mauris. Nulla tincidunt, nisl et dignissim mollis, sapien massa fermentum leo, volutpat porta 
             quam sem a erat. Pellentesque malesuada lectus sit amet dolor sollicitudin, vitae finibus magna molestie. Cras a ultrices libero. Etiam iaculis 
             sodales fringilla. Praesent commodo efficitur eros eu tincidunt. Ut ultricies aliquam tincidunt. Etiam feugiat elit in scelerisque vehicula. 
             Curabitur semper diam a erat finibus pretium.<br/><br/>Aenean sed est porttitor, bibendum lectus vehicula, facilisis lectus. Nam vehicula ligula 
             venenatis, lobortis lorem eu, fringilla nunc. Vestibulum ullamcorper sem vitae arcu suscipit iaculis. Etiam sodales nisl felis, nec tincidunt 
             arcu auctor nec. Sed suscipit hendrerit molestie. Vivamus finibus fermentum nunc non auctor. Mauris odio massa, dapibus quis fringilla in, 
             facilisis vel arcu. Nulla velit velit, tempor sit amet lacus quis, molestie condimentum sem. Vivamus a laoreet orci. Vestibulum dignissim ipsum 
             in quam placerat vulputate. Nullam malesuada et tortor vitae vestibulum. Aenean id mattis odio. Donec nec turpis lobortis, hendrerit nunc a, 
             vehicula odio. Pellentesque et ex ipsum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
         
      </div></div></div>
    </div>
 
          <div class="mastfoot">
            <div class="inner">
              <p>Built and designed for <a href="#">Pith and Prose</a>, by <a href="#">Paraclete</a>.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/js/docs.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: An example would be great.

Comment: Weird. It's slow for me, too. Chrome version 40.0 on Windows 7.

Comment: Yeah, and yet, in Safari on my Mac, it worked fine, although some of the margins, padding, etc. was off 1-2 px, but I can work on that. I just need it to be truly cross-platform.

Comment: The even more troubling part is that you're not loading it with the background image and it's still slow...

Comment: I turned off the `-webkit-box-shadow` effect on `site-wrapper` and it sped way up.

Comment: isn't that needed for Safari though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Box shadows take a long time to paint.](http://nerds.airbnb.com/box-shadows-are-expensive-to-paint/) It would probably be better to use a one-line image with `background-repeat-y` to get the inset shadow effect. That way Chrome knows it doesn't need to redraw the background and waste all that time calculating a huge area shadow effect. Alternately, the above link shows that just reducing the shadow blur radius can tremendously improve paint times.